# Hide table rows that don't have a certain class

Tags: jquery

```
function filterRows(statusName) {
    $("#mainTable tbody tr."+statusName).hide();
}
```

It hides the rows that have the class called `statusName`. How do I hide only the rows that don't have one?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

with the [`:not()` selector](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/)

```
$("#mainTable tbody tr:not(."+statusName + ')').hide();
```

Answer (score 3):

```
function filterRows(statusName) {
    $("#mainTable tbody tr."+statusName).siblings().hide();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use [`.hasClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/hasClass/) property

```
$("#mainTable tbody tr").map( function(){
if(!$(this).hasClass('statusName'))
{
  $(this).hide();
}
});
```

[`Working DEMO`](http://jsfiddle.net/X7NjY/1)

Answer (score 0):

or simply this:

```
$('#mainTable tbody tr').each(function() {     
$(this).not('.selected').hide()
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

I have created a quick POC for this. THis can give you an idea on how to customize it for your need. You can directly copy the following code and execute in a browser to see the result.

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="MVCDemoApp.Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="Scripts/jquery-1.7.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<head runat="server">
<title></title>
<style>
    .header
    {
        font-family: Verdana;
        font-size: large;
        background-color: Gray;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
    <table style="widt: 100%" id="mainTable">
        <tr class="header">
            <td>
                Head
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                No Class
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="header">
            <td>
                Header Class
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
</form>
</body>
<script>
/*
//Hides the rows with classes
$('table tr[class="header"]').hide(); 
*/

//hides the rows without classes
$('table tr[class!="header"]').hide(); 
</script>
</html>
```